# How to make a view controller as splash screen in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I am trying to make a view controller from storyboard as the splash screen in my application using swift 3. I am trying achieve the same effect as the splash screen does while loading the splash using "launch image". Since i have got an animation in the splash screen i wish to use a view controller as the splash screen in Swift 3. How to achieve this?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "splashScreen")

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try making A View Controller as rootViewController having a splash screen and after 2-3 seconds of showing that View Controller. Push / Present your initial ViewController.

You can set splash ViewController this way :-

```
self.window?.rootViewController = splashVC
```

In ViewDidLoad() of splashVC use timer or delay and after 2-3 seconds. Show your application's main View Controller.

```
//MARK:- Life Cycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.splashTimeOut(sender:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

func splashTimeOut(sender : Timer){
    AppDelegate.sharedInstance().window?.rootViewController = yourCustomViewController
    }
```

Add this method in Appdelegate for your convenience :-

```
class func sharedInstance() -> AppDelegate{
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
```

Comment: Yes, i wish to have that ViewDidLoad function in swift3 to push that main view controller. Please edit the answer with that . I will surely support it.

Comment: Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Let me check and get back soon.

Comment: Oukk if after the splash screen i need to show the introduction view (series of tutorial images) . That to needed to be seen only for first time. How to do this?

Comment: Put one key (Bool) in your NSUserDefaults and after the introduction series has been shown make it false, And after the spash timeout check if the key is true show series else go to normal home screen.

Comment: Where we have to give this Bool Key in Splash View Controller?

Comment: You can set this in the splash View Itself

Comment: What if the developer would like the splash to go to the next VC as soon as its ready, for example, if the next vc is ready before 2 seconds pass?